# T except one class

Tags: kotlin, generics

Suppose I've a class called `Devil`

```kotlin
class Devil
```

and I've method called `support`

```kotlin
fun <T> support(t : T){

}
```

I want to restrict this function to only accept classes other than `Devil` (all classes in the world, but not `Devil`). Something like

```kotlin
fun <T except Devil> support(t : T){

}
```

- How do I do this in Kotlin? Is this even possible?

Comment: This sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I agree with Sweeper here, something is fishy. What about supertypes and subtypes of `Devil`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is very likely an XY problem, so please do not apply this solution without considering something else.**

One way to achieve this is to declare a non-generic overload of `support()` with the explicit type `Devil`, and deprecate that function with `ERROR` level:

```kotlin
fun <T> support(t: T) {
    // do your stuff
}

@Deprecated("support() cannot be used with type Devil", level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR)
fun support(devil: Devil) {
    error("NOPE.")
}
```

Note that this would also exclude subtypes of `Devil` - which is not explicitly stated in your question, but might be what you want.

However, nothing prevents users from working around it by explicitly calling the generic overload by specifying a type in `<...>`:

```kotlin
support<Devil>(Devil()) // compiles fine
support<Any>(Devil()) // compiles fine
```

Similarly, as @gidds pointed out, this approach also doesn't prevent compilation if you pass in a variable with a static type that is not `Devil` even if it holds an instance of `Devil` (because the compiler will choose the generic overload in that case):

```kotlin
val hiddenDevil: Any = Devil()
support(hiddenDevil) // compiles fine
```

Comment: This is good for me. I am actually looking for a short-term solution that's quick to implement, and this should be fine. For the long term, I'll be writing a custom lint rule. Thanks for the detailed explanation along with the downside of this approach 

Comment: Note that overloads are resolved statically (at compile time), so this will only work if called with a value whose compile-time type is  `Devil`;  if you have an `Any` reference that happens to refer to a `Devil` instance, the generic method will be called.

Comment: @gidds good point. I added it to the answer as well

Comment: why didn't you use `fun support(a : Any)` instead of the generic variant? Then the barrier to use the `Devil`-overload is a bit higher due to the explicit cast..

Comment: @Roland I simply kept the original method declaration from the OP, assuming the generic was needed. If not, your suggestion is indeed a possibility, but it still doesn't always require a cast (you could simply declare a variable with a static type that's not `Devil`)

Comment: you are right.. in both cases..  still at least the call to `support` would be a bit more verbose if no explicit type was set due to a required cast instead of the generic type info... just wanted to mention it... probably there is more to it, so the generic type information makes sense... but... who knows...